# How to Receive Webhooks from Fundamerica in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks

I was working using the Fundamerica Rest API ,  Now I was stuck at a point where I need to Receive and Process webhooks sent by fundamerica. But I am unable to Receive those using the Generic webhooks receiver method in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks nuget Package. I have written a piece of code using the sample for genericreceivers as

```
public class GenericJsonWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public GenericJsonWebHookHandler()
    {
        this.Receiver = "genericjson";
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Get JSON from WebHook
        JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

        if (context.Id == "i")
        {
            // Received a WebHook from FundAmerica!
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Also I've Initialized the `Receiver` in WebHookConfig.cs as

```
config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
```

and Added the required key in app setting

```
key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_GenericJson" value="i={Secret}"
```

and Registered `WebHookConfig` in Global.asax.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebHookConfig.Register);
```

and Added the Url in Fundamerica Sandbox to post to our service(Hosted on Azure)

Url : `https://{host}.azurewebsites.net/api/webhooks/incoming/genericjson/i?code={Secret}`

The app is hosted on azure and I am debugging it locally but the webhook never hits the handler. I must be missing something or this is not the right path I am heading to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks